# Adjusted box plot in R

Tags: boxplot, adjustment

I was wandering if someone knows a package for adjusted box plot.

I want for example to draw this boxplot(age~groupe+sexe+other_variables)

Thanks in advance,

Peter

Answer (score 1):

Can't believe my answer was deleted. I don't know much about the stackoverflow rules, I don't know much about R (only studied r for 2 days), and I don't know much English even. I just happened to know this, and I was trying to help, since I've got lot help from the web. Let's try again.

> I was wandering if someone knows a package for adjusted box plot.

Yes. There's a package named `robustbase` in r. And specifically the `adjbox()' fun in the package.

> I want for example to draw this boxplot(age~groupe+sexe+other_variables)

Well, this is not a question. He meaned he wanted to do something, not he wanted examples, right (help my poor English)? Anyway you can draw an adjusted boxplot mainly like `adjbox(age~groupe+sexe+other_variables)`

Part of docstring of the func is as following:

```
adjbox(x, ..., range = 1.5, width = NULL, varwidth = FALSE,
     notch = FALSE, outline = TRUE, names, plot = TRUE,
     border = par("fg"), col = NULL, log = "",
     pars = list(boxwex = 0.8, staplewex = 0.5, outwex = 0.5),
     horizontal = FALSE, add = FALSE, at = NULL)
```

As for more details, you can try `help(adjbox)` in R, I think.
Here is some documents about the [fuc arguments](http://svitsrv25.epfl.ch/R-doc/library/robustbase/html/adjbox.html), and about the [package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/robustbase/robustbase.pdf).

Though I think "Yes, there's a func called `adjbox` in a package called `robustbase` in R can do that" was pretty enough to answer the question, especially for an R user, because R is well knowned as its good self documenting packages. And I don't think a long answer is gonna do more help. `But still I'm trying to give a better answer.` If somebody has a better answer, then answer. If somebody can modify my answer to be better, I'm fine with that Or if anybody can help me, I'm open to it, because I do actually need help on R and on English. But by just deleting the only answer isn't gonna help more. After all, I wasn't like asking for any voting, or demanding mine to be the best answer, or prevending others to answer it. Nor am I delivering wrong information.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function named [adjbox](http://svitsrv25.epfl.ch/R-doc/library/robustbase/html/adjbox.html) in the package robustbase.

As for the document for adjbox: http://svitsrv25.epfl.ch/R-doc/library/robustbase/html/adjbox.html

And the document for the robustbase: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/robustbase/robustbase.pdf